# Linq - Get all items between 2 matching elements

Tags: c#, linq

Provided a list, I want to select all items between the 2 given. (including the begin and end params)

My current solution is as follows:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetAllBetween(IEnumerable<string> list, string begin, string end)
{
    bool isBetween = false;
    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        if (item == begin)
        {
            isBetween = true;
        }
        if (item == end)
        {
            yield return item;
            yield break;
        }
        if (isBetween)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

But surely there must be a pretty linq query that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: Why would there be something pretty? This is not a frequent task.

Comment: It just looks like alot of code for a simple task so I'd expect this could be reduced to 3-5 lines with Linq?

Comment: Indeed, I agree with John Saunders. Although, you could write it as an extension method if you use it often.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can *nearly* use `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile`, but you want the last item as well - you want the functionality of [`TakeUntil`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs) from [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq). You can then use:

```
var query = source.SkipWhile(x => x != begin)
                  .TakeUntil(x => x == end);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    static IEnumerable<T> GetAllBetween<T>( this List<T> list, T a, T b )
    {
        var aOffset = list.IndexOf( a );
        var bOffset = list.IndexOf( b );

        // what to do if one or all items not found?
        if( -1 == aOffset || -1 == bOffset )
        {
            // for this example I will return an empty array
            return new T[] { };
        }

        // what to do if a comes after b?
        if( aOffset > bOffset )
        {
            // for this example i'll simply swap them
            int temp = aOffset;
            aOffset = bOffset;
            bOffset = temp;
        }

        return list.GetRange( aOffset, bOffset - aOffset );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `Skip`, `Take` should do it. I normally take it for paging ASP.NET resultsites.

```
 var startIndex = list.IndexOf(begin);
 var endIndex = list.IndexOf(end);
 var result = list.Skip(startIndex + 1).Take(endIndex - 1 - startIndex);
```